# disaggregate using raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to disaggregate an existing raster with a cell size of 10000 to a new one of 2000. The larger raster represents the UK in 10km squares, and I want the same extent but in 2km squares. I am using the disaggregate function in the raster package, but what should be simple task returns an error message `Error in .local(x, values) : values must be a vector`

The larger raster does according to the raster properties in ArcGIS have nodata values set to -32768, and I have tried changing these to 0

```
grid10[grid10==-32768] <- 0 

# and in case there are NA's

grid10[is.na(grid10[])] <- 0

# but these make no difference  

grid2 <- disaggregate(grid10, fact=5) # i.e 10000 to 2000 is 5 times smaller
```

> Error in .local(x, values) : values must be a vector

What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us more details? Include the print out of str(grid2), and that of sessionInfo().

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was because my R version had got removed with repairs due to computer issues, and so I was unwittingly running a 2010 version of R and a very old version of raster. New versions of both installed and all works fine.

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer so we can consider this question resolved.